# How to set device-specific mouse settings in Wayland under Libinput (Debian Gnome)?

Tags: debian, mouse, wayland

I am running a Thinkpad T470. I often dock this, meaning I have 3 mouse input devices (external Microsoft mouse, Trackpoint, and Trackpad). I'm running Debian 10 (Testing - Buster) using Gnome under Wayland.

In Gnome settings (below) I can change the sensitivity of the "Mouse" by configuring "Mouse Sensitivity". However, this changes the sensitivity of *both* the external mouse and the trackpoint. I like to have my trackpoint on low sensitivity, and the mouse on high.

[image: Gnome Mouse Settings]

Under Xorg, I could make a simple script to set device specific configuration settings. How would I achieve this in Wayland?

Comment: I had a [similar problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/608920/how-can-i-change-my-trackballs-scroll-method-in-gnome-on-wayland) which I managed to solve by looking at the output of `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.peripherals`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wayland expects all mice motion to have been [normalised](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/normalization-of-relative-motion.html), so there is only one global changeable configuration. You may have to edit your [hwdb](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/tree/hwdb/70-mouse.hwdb) entry for one of your devices to correct it if it is wrong, or just make it fit in with your preferences.

Alternatively, you may be able to use `libevdev-tweak-device` from the package `libevdev-tools` (or `libevdev-utils`).  It says it can alter the definition of an evdev device dynamically. You would do something like

```
sudo libevdev-tweak-device --abs ABS_X --res 99 /dev/input/event99
sudo libevdev-tweak-device --abs ABS_Y --res 99 /dev/input/event99
```

where you need to replace the *99* by the resolution you want, and *event99* by the input device. You can find the input device from, eg:

```
$ ls -l /dev/input/by-id/
lrwxrwxrwx ... usb-Logitech_USB_Optical_Mouse-event-mouse -> ../event5
```

To find the current resolution try `sudo evemu-describe` from the `evemu-tools` package, or use `mouse-dpi-tool` to try to choose a good value.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem and tried to fix it by adding an entry to `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/71-mouse-local.hwdb` using the `mouse-dpi-tool` as describe in the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/422867/89141) currently most up-voted. A great tool which gave me the idea I was on the right track but whatever I was trying it didn't work. Having said that some difference between 400 and 800 DPI seemed to have effect but increasing it to higher than 800 seemed to do the opposite again.

Then successfully managed to increase the speed by changing the acceleration profile using the [dconf editor](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DconfEditor) at `org/gnome/desktop/peripherals`, which can be installed from your Linux repo. Also played with the speed variable, accepting a (double) value in the range from -1 to 1. Double meaning it can be a fraction number such as -0.5 or 0.5. Ended up with setting it to 1.0 which was the initial value when I started using the dconf editor already. Not sure if changing it was part of the solution or that the adaptive acceleration profile I selected had to calibrate itself. Saying that it needed a few minutes to move the mouse pointer faster finally.

Comment: All what Arnaud Kleinveld said :) , but I used -0.99, it seems to be slower that -1.0

Answer (score 1):

I did it on an x230 with Debian 10 by writing this file to '/etc/udev/hwdb.d/71-pointingstick-local.hwdb':

```
# /etc/udev/hwdb.d/71-pointingstick-local.hwdb
#
# This file contains a custom "hwdb" entry to set pointing stick speed for
# Wayland by "normalizing" device dpi. (for details see:
# https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/normalization-of-relative-motion.html).
# 
# My purpose is to set touchpoint speed seperate from external mouse so I don't have
# to change it by hand every time I plug in a mouse. The touchpoint got un-useably 
# over sensitive with the last update. This worked on Debian 10, might also 
# work on Ubuntu or other derivates, circa ~2019. Good luck until they change it again :/
#
# copy the stanza for your device from /usr/lib/udev/hwdb.d/70-pointingstick.hwdb
# into this file.
#
# per https://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/tree/hwdb/70-mouse.hwdb
# edit sensitivity, then run:
# sudo udevadm hwdb --update
# sudo udevadm trigger /dev/input/event6 #(with your device number)
# 
# input device can be discovered with:
# sudo libinput list-devices | grep -A 20 TrackPoint

# Lenovo Thinkpad X230
evdev:name:TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:svnLENOVO:pn*:pvrThinkPadX230:*
#POINTINGSTICK_SENSITIVITY=400 # Too fast!
 POINTINGSTICK_SENSITIVITY=100 # better...
 POINTINGSTICK_CONST_ACCEL=1.0
```