# How can I change my trackball's scroll method in GNOME on Wayland?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, wayland, libinput

I like using [libinput's on-button scrolling feature](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/scrolling.html#on-button-scrolling) to make my trackball a scroll wheel when holding down `BTN_BACK`. The [Arch Linux wiki describes](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/libinput#Scroll_with_mouse_by_holding_a_button) how to configure this feature in Xorg. When I used [sway](https://swaywm.org/), I was able to get the behaviour I wanted using the following configuration documented in [sway-input(5)](https://manpages.debian.org/experimental/sway/sway-input.5.en.html):

```
input <identifier> {
  scroll_method on_button_down
  scroll_button BTN_BACK
}
```

I recently switched to GNOME on Wayland. But I can't figure out how to configure my scroll method in GNOME Shell. According to the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/libinput#Scroll_with_mouse_by_holding_a_button), libinput's configurable options depend on your desktop environment's support for them, and I can't find anything relevant in GNOME Settings or GNOME Tweaks.

### See also

- [How to set device-specific mouse settings in Wayland under Libinput (Debian Gnome)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/422470/how-to-set-device-specific-mouse-settings-in-wayland-under-libinput-debian-gnom?rq=1) (unix.SE)
- [How to configure libinput under gnome wayland?](https://reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/asanqt/how_to_configure_libinput_under_gnome_wayland/) (reddit)

Comment: I don't think Gnome currently provides the necessary setting. I remember, Gnome does provide more settings than you can change with GUI. To modify ones not presented by GUI, you have to use `gsettings` utility. So, when I execute `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.peripherals`, I don't see a `scroll-method` option on my system, which likely means it's not provided at all. You will have to report a feature-request, not sure exactly where, but I think [to gnome-shell](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell).

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Interestingly, when I run that `gsettings` command I get `org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.trackball scroll-wheel-emulation-button 0`. Maybe this option is only available for trackballs? I'll keep investigating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This option can be configured (for trackballs only) using the `scroll-wheel-emulation-button` setting. By default this is set to `0`, meaning that no button will turn the trackball into a scroll wheel. I experimented with a few different mouse buttons and found that button `5` was the most convenient for scrolling on my trackball:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.trackball scroll-wheel-emulation-button 5
```

This worked immediately, without needing to reboot or restart my GNOME session, in GNOME Shell 3.36. The feature was [added in GNOME 3.16](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=645666) (March 2015).

Answer (score 1):

You can play with the gsettings in dconf-editor if you like a GUI.
I used to have mine set to press and hold right click for scroll (button 3), but that doesn't seem to work for Wayland, the context menu tends to appear first so scrolling doesn't work.
Changed to the Back button (button 8) and found it workable. Back still works on click, press and hold for scroll.
As you say no need to restart Gnome to apply the settings.